Google Drive API - iOS/Android - How can user allow access to file?
My iOS/Android app is using "drive.file" scope for Google Drive API.  I want to be able to download files the user has created.  In order for my app to see the file, the user has to authorize access somehow on a per-file basis.  I'm struggling with how to do this.
There is a Google Picker, but it seems to be Javascript based and require using a web browser, and sounds too cumbersome to deal with.
I was then thinking I could use Google's official Drive app where users could send a file to my app, thus authorizing it.  I gave my authentication process a scope of "drive.install" also, but no help so far.  When I send a file from Drive app to another app (using "Open In"),

My app doesn't show up. I might need to specify a mime type, but also
Drive seems to convert my Google Sheet file to PDF before trying to send to an app, and I don't want a PDF, I just want access to read the Sheet file "normally" (my app can choose how to open/convert).

I know how to retrieve a list of files from Google Drive and download, but when using the "file" scope, I can only see files the user has authorized, and I don't know a practical way for user to give my app access.  Can anyone provide some guidance?
Thanks,
Ernie
For some background, my app currently uses full "drive" access, but Google is now requiring me (and others, I've seen) to complete an annual CASA Tier 2 security assessment (costing at least $500 USD per year) in order to continue using such open access (to all user's files).  Without this completed assessment, and with full "drive" access, the user login screen shows "Google hasn't verified this app" warning, makes it difficult for user to get around warning, and finally imposes a user limit on how many people can log in.  It's not workable in production environment.  So, I'm trying to work with the more restrictive "drive.file" scope, but I don't understand how Google expects a user to be able to authorize a user's file to be opened within a mobile app.

Have you tried adding https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive as this scope allows you to view and manage all your Drive files? You may also browse this article for a list of Google Drive API Scopes.

Yes. My app currently uses this scope, but Google is effectively blocking me from using it anymore. They are clamping down on security risks.

Can you please give more details about Google is effectively blocking me from using it anymore? You may edit your post and add some screenshots or error messages pertaining to this issue.

Hi Patrick.  Thanks for your interested in helping.  I updated my question.  I think it likely that I will have to drop Google Drive support.  I want my app to be able to open Excel and Sheet files that the user has created, but I don't yet see a workable solution.  The problem is my app currently does not have access to read these files.  With "drive.file" scope, the app can only access files that the app has created, or that the user somehow authorizes.  In Google's words, "that the user shares with an app while using the Google Picker API or the app's file picker".
